# TFRecords parsing: How to retrieve multiple images from a single tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to parse a dataset with coco format, consisting of (among others) a input image, and a list of images(masks) as output.
The dataset has been converted to tfrecords using [efficientdet/dataset_tools/create_coco_record.py](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/dataset/create_coco_tfrecord.py)

Following is a snippet of the serialization:

```
feature_dict = {
      'image/height':
          tfrecord_util.int64_feature(image_height),
      'image/width':
          tfrecord_util.int64_feature(image_width)
      'image/encoded':
          tfrecord_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
  }
...
for object_annotations in bbox_annotations:
    run_len_encoding = mask.frPyObjects(object_annotations['segmentation'],
                                            image_height, image_width)
    binary_mask = mask.decode(run_len_encoding)
    binary_mask = np.amax(binary_mask, axis=2)
    pil_image = PIL.Image.fromarray(binary_mask)
    output_io = io.BytesIO()
    pil_image.save(output_io, format='PNG')
    encoded_mask_png.append(output_io.getvalue()

if include_masks:
    feature_dict['image/object/mask'] = (
        tfrecord_util.bytes_list_feature(encoded_mask_png))
```

My problem comes with the decoding of the tfrecords, where I am unable to decode the images within the mask tensor.

Following is my parsing function:

```
def parse_example(serialized_example):
  feature_dict = {
    'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/encoded':  tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'image/object/class/label': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
    'image/object/mask': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.string, allow_missing=True),
  }

  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature_dict)

  raw_height = tf.cast(example['image/height'], tf.int64)
  raw_width = tf.cast(example['image/width'], tf.int64)
  image = tf.image.decode_png(example['image/encoded'], channels=3)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (512, 512))
  labels = example['image/object/class/label'] 

  masks = tf.image.decode_png(example['image/object/mask'], channels=3)
```

Error I recieve:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node DecodePng_1}} = DecodePngchannels=3, dtype=DT_UINT8' with input shapes: [?].

How would I go about decoding multiple images in a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found at [tf_example_decoder.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/dataloader/tf_example_decoder.py).

Following is a few snippets of the code:

Read the images as VarLenFeatures with type string

```
keys_to_features = {
...
'image/object/mask': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string)
}

parsed_tensors = tf.io.parse_single_example(
        serialized=serialized_example, features=keys_to_features)
```

Convert sparse to dense tensor

```
for k in parsed_tensors:
  if isinstance(parsed_tensors[k], tf.SparseTensor):
    if parsed_tensors[k].dtype == tf.string:
      parsed_tensors[k] = tf.sparse.to_dense(
          parsed_tensors[k], default_value='')
```

Then decode the masks using:

```
def _decode_masks(self, parsed_tensors):
    """Decode a set of PNG masks to the tf.float32 tensors."""
    def _decode_png_mask(png_bytes):
      mask = tf.squeeze(
          tf.io.decode_png(png_bytes, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint8), axis=-1)
      mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32)
      mask.set_shape([None, None])
      return mask

    height = parsed_tensors['image/height']
    width = parsed_tensors['image/width']
    masks = parsed_tensors['image/object/mask']
    return tf.cond(
        pred=tf.greater(tf.size(input=masks), 0),
        true_fn=lambda: tf.map_fn(_decode_png_mask, masks, dtype=tf.float32),
        false_fn=lambda: tf.zeros([0, height, width], dtype=tf.float32))
```